# How do you round decimal of an expression in mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, rounding

I would like to know how to round to 1 decimal place of the numbers in an **expression**.

For instance, the mathematica gave me `0.7888888888000002*x+1.0000000002*x^2+2.1000002*x^3==0`, I want to know how do I round up these digits in mathematica.

I have browsed around the web for half an hour now and I coulnd't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all Real numbers with those numbers numbers rounded to .1

```
In[1]:= ReplaceAll[0.7888888888000002*x+1.0000000002*x^2+2.1000002*x^3==0, 
   n_Real->Round[n, .1]]

Out[1]= 0.8 x + 1. x^2 + 2.1 x^3 == 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You said "round up" yet Bill recommended `Round` which does not behave this way.  For that replace `Round` in his code with `Ceiling`.

If rounding is actually what you want (since you Accepted that answer) consider also using `Rationalize`.  Rational numbers will be handled with infinite precision with can be good or bad depending on what you're doing.  Unlike `Round` it will automatically thread over expressions so you do not need to use `ReplaceAll` etc.:

```
eq = 0.7888888888000002*x + 1.0000000002*x^2 + 2.1000002*x^3 == 0

Rationalize[eq, 0.02]
```

> ```
> (4 x)/5 + x^2 + (19 x^3)/9 == 0
> ```

Note that using exact arithmetic lets *Mathematica* eliminate the coefficient of the second term.

As with `Round` and `Ceiling` the second parameter determines the granularity of the operation.

---

Visit the dedicated *Mathematica* Stack Exchange site:

[image: Mathematica.StackExchange]